# HLA Starter Kit

Tags: simulation, high-level-architecture

Where can I find an introduction to the [High Level Architecture (HLA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Level_Architecture) to help me build a distributed simulation?

Comment: I've changed the tag, since the `hla` tag refers to High Level Assembly, not High Level Architecture (simulation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tutorial can be found on http://www.pitch.se/hlatutorial.